# Add field separator 1C in hex (Java)

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, hex, ascii

I need to use "1C" (hex) as a field separator in my messages. But when I manually put 1C in the message and view the hex output of the final message in UltraEdit I see 31 63 instead, i.e. hexadcimal equivalents of 1 and C. How do I make sure that it stays as 1C in the hex output as well? There is no ASCII equivalent of it that I can put in the message.

Upon opening a sample request message I have, I see only a "." (dot) in the ASCII string and 1C in the hex dump on UltraEdit, and that is what I want it to be. In fact Notepad++ shows it as "FS" as well, but shows only 1C for my message.

Thanks.

Comment: The char literal `\u001C` should do the trick.

Comment: What is consuming your messages and how are you sending them?

Comment: Being sent over a Socket (im the client) and the server is in Java as well I believe. But we are having to use this encoding because I am only simulating in Java what a payment terminal (coded in C) would do and 1C is a standard field separator there.

Comment: Be very sure you use the same encoding as the payment terminal when converting your String into bytes then.

Comment: It sounds like you need to work with ASCII messages. If that's the case, you probably shouldn't be constructing entire Unicode messages and then converting them to ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a character with value 1C by writing `'\u001c'` as a character constant, or inclding `"…\u001c…"` in a string literal.

Comment: Thanks, @JoachimSauer, was just checking that after writing the answer. Too much C lately, I guess.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: If you had written your answer as an answer instead of a comment, I wouldn't have to copy it, but could have deleted mine instead. :)

Comment: Some answers are not *Answer*-worthy in my book. Therefore the answering comment.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Not answering using an answer will cause the question to remain technically unanswered for longer than required. So it will only lead more people to spend more time on those “unworthy” questions.

Comment: Most people don't accept the answers, anyway. I've stopped bothering along the way. You have my support to leave your answer, of course, I don't mind.

Comment: As long as Marko doesn't have an issue, I will accept this as the correct answer, in case someone looks it up in the future.

Comment: A character is not equal to a byte. You should encode the string first, then add a `byte` to the array.

Comment: @artbristol: Granted, my solution assumes the eoncoding to be a superset of ASCII.

Comment: Not a great assumption to make - why not do it properly?

Comment: @artbristol: There are many cases where that assumption is perfectly valid, e.g. if you only require the code to run in a specific setup, or know which encoding will be used when writing the file. Feel free to provide your own answer, as it is a real alternative which might be worth considering, depending on requirements.

Answer (score 1):

How do you store the message? The following works just fine:

```
String message = "some\u001ctext\n";
for (byte b : message.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) {
    System.out.println(b);
}

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("message.txt", "ISO-8859-1");
writer.append(message);
writer.close();
```

(updated according to comments)

Comment: You are of course right, the lines should read `message.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")` and `new PrintWriter(fileName, "ISO-8859-1")`

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I cannot follow you on UTF-8 *not* encoding U+001C as 0x1c. DOing so follows the specs and works on my system. Where do you see the problem there?

Comment: @MvG: of course you're right. I should stop posting today, I read the value as C1! All ASCII-compatible encodings will of course encode U+001C as 0x1C.

Answer (score 1):

How about using this notation?

```
public static final byte FIELD_SEPARATOR   = 0x1C;
```